# Como definir uma subclasse de uma classe abstrata de forma que ela seja concreta

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, c++11, classes-abstratas

Com estas classes:

```
class SerVivo {
 public:
  virtual void funcA() = 0;
  virtual void funcB() = 0;
};

class Vegetal : public SerVivo{
 public:
  virtual void funcB(){ cout << "funcB em Vegetal \n"; }
  virtual void funcC() = 0;
};
```

Queria saber como é que construo a classe Arvore, derivada de Vegetal, de modo a poder construir objetos do tipo Arvore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa implementar todas as funções *puramente virtuais* (definidas como "`virtual nome_da_duncao(...) = 0`" ) da hierarquia. Como `Arvore` é descendente de `Vegetal`, ela precisa implementar `funcC`. Mas como `Vegetal` é descendente de `SerVivo`, ela também precisa implementar `funcA`. Não precisa implementar `funcB` porque essa já foi implementada em Vegetal.

Exemplo:

```
class Arvore : public Vegetal {
public:
    void funcA() { cout << "funcA em Arvore \n"; }
    void funcC() { cout << "funcC em Arvore \n"; }
};


int main()
{

    Arvore arvore1{};
    arvore1.funcA();
    arvore1.funcB();
    arvore1.funcC();

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
funcA em Arvore                                                                                                                                                                             
funcB em Vegetal                                                                                                                                                                            
funcC em Arvore


...Program finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :)